# Sum a subsection of a query result column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, t-sql

I have an interesting problem and am having trouble figuring it out. I'm trying to optimize some SQL queries by handling some of the result separation with PHP rather than running multiple SQL queries. My query returns the following:

[image]

Using PHP, is there a way to sum the results by 'processor'? So, for example, I want be able to echo out '36.00' for PayPal and so forth. I'm currently able to do this with multiple individual queries, but am relatively confident there's a way to do this with one query and using PHP - I just can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Create an associative array whose keys are the processor. Loop over the results of the query, and do `array[$row['processor']] += $row['payment_amount']`.

Comment: DBMS was created for this, don't eat their bread.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just want a `group by` query:

```
select processor, sum(payment_amount)
from t
group by processor;
```

There is no reason to do this work in PHP.

Comment: I don't want to group by processor because I need to take the 'payment_datetime' into account as well. So I'd want to be able to sum the amounts where the processor is paypal and the payment_datetime > whatever datetime I'm narrowing down to.

Comment: @rtoken Maybe next time you should include your desire output as well. So the question would be more clear. Btw on your question you didnt mention anything regarding date. But just add a `WHERE payment_datetime  > #date# ` here and you will be ok

Comment: @rtoken . . . That is not the question you asked.  You *can* add a a `where` clause or ask a new question with appropriate data, desired results, and explanation of what you are doing.